# larger images cutting of in reveal.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reveal.js

I'm using reveal js slideshow but it it larger images are cutting of as shown in this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/haa7wr

I want it show complete image but it's design is added via js and it's inline styling so my style is not overriding it or may be I wasn't doing it correctly.

```
.reveal section img { background-size: contain !important; }
```

Comment: can you try { background-size cover; background-position: center center; }

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst no it didn't changed anything. Even i tried to add this style doing inspect element but it remain as it is.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and post it in your question?

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst the answer given by Jordi worked for me. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've got to override this style:

```
.reveal .slide-background {
      background-size: contain !important;
}
```